# "Coda" e "fila" sono due cose diverse?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Vorrei sapere se c'è qualche differenza nell'uso tra "coda" e "fila". Diverse volte ho sentito le due forme.

Secondo me, è la stessa cosa, però, quando leggo un testo come

> "La prima è che sei minuti è la durata media oltre la quale le persone
>   cominciano a spazientirsi quando stanno in fila (non quella dopo cui
>   abbandonano la coda)"

non riesco a capire se "coda" è una cosa
specifica o "coda" è usata, in questo caso, per evitare la ripetizione della parola "fila".

Comment: Welcome su ItalianSE!

Comment: Mi sembra che chiunque abbia scritto quella frase segua un po' troppo alla lettera la buona norma di evitare le ripetizioni – a costo di provocare possibili equivoci, come qui – e soprattutto abbia dimenticato l'esistenza dei pronomi, che sono stati inventati esattamente per casi così (“...non quella dopo cui la abbandonano”). [Certo, anche “quella” è un pronome.]

Comment: Ottima osservazione!

Comment: ...e, comunque, *è così poco da italiani mettersi in coda* (pubblicità della British Airways dei primi anni 2000).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nel contesto da te citato coda e fila possono essere considerati sinonimi.

Dalla definizione di [**fila**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fila/) per Treccani:

> 1. Disposizione di persone o cose poste una di seguito all'altra su una medesima linea; e le persone o le cose stesse così disposte

dalla definizione di [**coda**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/coda) per Treccani:

> 4. c. Parte finale di una fila: *la c. del treno*; *il vagone di c.*,
>      l’ultimo; fanalino di c., che mostra, nel buio, dove finisce il treno
>      (e per traslato scherz., l’ultimo in una graduatoria); *la c. d’una
>      colonna in marcia; gli uomini di c.* (ma detto in contrapp. a capo,
>      indica gli ultimi d’una gerarchia: *i capi e le c.; non sono capo ma
>      neanche c.); mettersi in c., **fare la c.,*** far la fila, mettersi in fila
>      davanti a uno sportello, a un banco e sim., aspettando il proprio
>      turno: *fare la c. alla biglietteria della stazione*.

Come puoi vedere la coda sarebbe la parte finale della fila, anche se devo dire nuovamente che in questo contesto vengono usate nella maggior parte dei casi come sinonimi.

Comment: Se c’è la fila allo sportello, ci si mette *in coda*; da qui a considerare *coda* e *fila* come sinonimi, in questo contesto, il passo è stato breve.

Comment: Bravo! Grazie mille, ragazzi!